# How to get Asp.net Core Identity User in View

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In Asp.net core mvc project, how to get the current IdentityUser information in View ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What @rdhainaut said works OK if you just want to display the username on the View. If that's all you need, you can even use the following without the needs of injecting anything!

```cs
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div>Hello, @User.Identity.Name</div>
}
```

The reason is, with the default configuration (assuming you're using username), the username is stored in `@User.Identity.Name` after successful signin.

Now if you do want to display additional information about the logged in user, such as display name on your site top navigation, that's when I think ViewComponent` comes into play!

For example, let's say you have defined an `Admin` area in your MVC project and you want to create a top navigation bar.

1. You create a folded called `ViewComponents` under `Admin` folder.
2. Create a view component called `TopNavbarViewComponent.cs`.

   ```cs
   public class TopNavbarViewComponent : ViewComponent
   {
       private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

       // You can inject anything you want here
       public TopNavbarViewComponent(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
       {
           _userManager = userManager;
       }

       public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
       {
           var appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(
               HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

           var vm = new TopNavbarViewModel
           {
               // Just as an example... perhaps you have additional 
               // property like FirstName and LastName in your IdentityUser.
               DisplayName = appUser?.DisplayName,
               Email = appUser?.Email,
               Phone = appUser?.PhoneNumber
           };

           return View(vm);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Define the model behind the view undler `ViewComponents\Models`.

   ```cs
   public class TopNavbarViewModel
   {
       public string DisplayName { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Phone { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Define the view for the view component, which needs to be under `Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\Components\TopNavbar\Default.cshtml` by convention.

   ```cs
   @model Web.UI.Areas.Admin.ViewComponents.Models.TopNavbarViewModel

   <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Hello, @Model.DisplayName
           </a>
       </ul>
   </nav>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer !
View component are really usefull for that kind of case

Comment: Thank you for one of the most complete answers I have seen here.  To often people give 1/2 answers and it really does not help.  Especially with something like Core 3.0 which seems to have more than its fair share of magic going on in the background.   I used your answer and this page by MS which details how to change some of the defaults.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 5):

In a web application asp.net core mvc 2.0, You can have the IdentityUser object  directly available in the view with the following code :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <div>Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</div>
}
```